# Windows Fails to Login when Media HDD Removed

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, login

I have an interesting issue and Googling it hasn't brought up anything significant.

I have a media drive (P:) on my Windows 10 that I tried to remove as I had copied all contents to a new drive.

I removed the HDD from my tower and when booting I can get to the Login screen just fine (since it wasn't the boot drive) but once I sign-in the screen goes blank.  I can still move and see my cursor.  I can CTRL+ALT+DEL and can click on Task Manager but it never comes up, it just goes back to the blank cursor screen.

Once I add my media HDD back in to my tower then I'm able to Login as I would expect.

So I'm not even sure where to really start.

Perhaps Windows is still referencing something on the drive that's needed to complete the Login load?  I did have the Windows Explorer Music/Videos/Pictures folders referencing folders on that drive.  I did switch them prior to HDD removal to my new drive.

Anything else I can try so that I can remove this HDD and still boot into Windows?

Comment: Look at your startups - a good tool is [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns). Search also the registry for the string `X:` (X stands for the drive when connected) - a good tool is [RegScanner](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html).

Comment: Good ideas, Autoruns turned up no results that had the drive letter on the path (P:).  The RegScanner found a couple of things, nothing seems like it would be an issue.  Here's a paste of those items:  https://pastebin.com/amX4Z3Bz

Comment: Are you using that drive as part of the system, e.g., for *ReadyBoost*? Do you have *Restore* turned on for that drive? Are any of the *Startup* applications listed in *Task Manager* storing data there? Are there cloud apps that have data folders there?

Comment: Nope to all of those.  It's a pretty bare-bones drive where I stick Pictures/Musice/Videos.  No applications on it, no cloud backup, no Restore for it.

Comment: @Fernker: The registry entries you found are harmless. I suggest to test Windows integrity by running [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Answer (score 1):

Did you change in the Properties for your user-account the home-folder setting to use a "Local Path" with a path referring to P:\ ?
(The field is normally blank.)
I have seen people do that before and it can have some really weird side-effects, like this one.
Just changing it back to blank should fix that.

Comment: Possibly, where do I go to see this property?   I poked around in my account settings but wasn't able to see something like this.

Comment: You would have seen it in the registry, but your search didn't find it there.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh I found the issue.

For some reason Windows changed my new HDD back to the initial drive letter (F:) and so my Quick Access Music/Pictures/Video were pointed to (E:) and it couldn't find it so it couldn't load.

I'm not sure why Windows changed the drive-letter back but I guess I'll have to keep an eye on it and see when it happens again.

Doing some searching on this problem and it seems Windows just sometimes does this.